# Where to ask about ownCloud?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Asking about [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/) seems to be off-topic on [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com), because it is not a generally public app.

What is the best place on the Stack Exchange network for questions about ownCloud?

Here is an example question:

> How to synchronize contacts and calendar entries with an older Nokia
>   Phone (that runs with the Symbian OS)? The phone uses SyncML as far as
>   I can tell and I have also an exchange client installed, as an
>   alternative.
>
> OwnCloud seems not to support either of the protocols out of the box.
>   Are there Extensions or Plugins for either ownCloud or my phone to
>   make that work?

Comment: I guess half of the time it would be their issue queue anyway ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, let's try it. If the question is about…

- **…setting up and managing OwnCloud.** *Maybe* [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), they have an owncloud-tag, but not very popular so I can't guarantee that they will accept these questions. Ask on their Meta. Also it is quite possible that [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) accepts those questions; again, ask first.
- **…usage of OwnCloud.** Well, in theory [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) should accept those, *but* they explicitly exclude (self-)hosted stuff like WordPress, so they don't seem to do OwnCloud. [Super User](https://superuser.com/) is definitely off-limits, and I don't see any other site which this might fit, so your best bet is to go to OwnCloud's own forums/IRC/similar.
- **…writing plugins for/extending OwnCloud.** In theory, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), but asking the OwnCloud community directly would be a way better option.

Regarding your example, it is a question of the type "is there a software that does x?" and is not a good fit anywhere on Stack Exchange.